# How to handle events in redux? (Specifically async ones)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hello guys so I'm trying to handle events from async redux actions but i'm not sure how to do it correctly? In my code my AddTopping() handler calls the action creator and then the proccess cycles through. I logged everything to console.log --- based on the code below this is what the console.log will print out in order  assuming the function executes fine:

```
success is 'pending'
success is true
```

It prints the initial state first which is what I don't want. I would have to call the action creator twice to actually get the 'true' for the object. I can do a setTimeout to 50 millisec and it will work but I don't want to make setTimeout's everytime. How will I handle this the right way?

**Component that calls the action creator:**

```
class Milk extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.AddTopping.bind(this);
  }
  AddTopping() {
    this.props.addChocolate({TableName: 'Dark', Item: {title: 'someCake'}});

    if (this.props.birthdayCake.send_success === true) {
      console.log('Congrats you have added chocolate to the cake');
    } else {
      console.log('You have failed to add chocolate to the cake.');
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Chocolate is great.</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**the action creator that will then call the reducer:**

```
export const addChocolate = (darkOrLight) => {
  return ( dispatch ) => {
    someAsyncFunction(darkOrLight, (err,data) => {
      if (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_CHOCOLATE', success: false });
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_CHOCOLATE', success: true });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**the reducer which will now update the state in the application:**

```
const initialState = { send_success: 'pending' }
export function birthdayCake( state=initialState, action) {
  switch ( action.type ) {
    case ADD_CHOCOLATE:
      if (action.success === true) {
        return Object.assign({}, state, { send_success: true });
      } else {
        return Object.assign({}, state, { send_success: false });
      }
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to handle it manually, Redux will take care of that. once the state is updated the component will be re-rendered.

Where are you calling the log function?

Comment: Just a wild guess here, but this async behavior you require could be solved with redux-thunk.